# How to get the integer value of month from moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using Moment.js for adding dates to an option list I am making, so that I can use those dates to show available appointments, for example, someone can select Friday, February 3rd from the option list and then a list of available times will show up for February 3rd.

What I am having trouble with is I am using an online scheduling api that takes month values that start at 1, for example, January is 01, February is 02, etc. but moment.js months start at 0 and only go up to 11, for example, January is 0, February is 1, etc. I need to be able to convert the values from moment.js into an integer so I can add 1 to each to account for the difference.

The real problem is I tried using parseInt(Month) to get the int value to add one to it, but that didn't work. Here is my code attempting to do just that:

```
var d = moment(),  
Month = d.month();

var GetMonthint = parseInt(Month),
    GetMonth = GetMonthint++;

        GetAppointmentDates(GetMonth, Year);
```

GetMonth still only returns 1 for February, is there some special way I can get the int value from the month?

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` and the postfix increment operator? Do you know about the difference between postfix and prefix incrementation?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
GetMonth = GetMonthint++;
```

is the problem. The ++ operator returns the original value not the incremented value. You should do this:

```
GetMonth = GetMonthint + 1;
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I guess I'm a little too used to PHP formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Actually you should just do `GetMonth = GetMonthInt + 1;` It shows the intent much better than using either the postfix or prefix operator.

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: @EricBrown PHP formatting? What does that have to do with anything? The same line in PHP will do the exact same thing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm personally more used to using ++ for adding since I work with a lot of loops that require it.

Comment: @EricBrown So... you're used to doing it the wrong way? Basically, in a loop, using ++ makes sense, since you're presumably incrementing a counter for each loop. Thus you're not using the incremented value except as a loop terminator. In this case, you have two variables and want to set one equal to the other, plus one. What better way to show that than one variable = other + 1?